# Angular js app not defined warning

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is my first attempt to create a sample angular application. 
In `app.js` I defined the following -

```
var app = angular.module('myTestApp', ['ngCookies',
                                       'ngResource',
                                       'ngRoute',
                                       'ngSanitize',
                                       'ngTouch']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 routeProvider
 .when('sample', {
    templateUrl: 'views/sample.html',
    controller: 'sampleCtrl'
  })
});
```

I have created corresponding `sample.js` for controller,  `sample.html` for template and `sampleModel.js` for model.
In grunt console, it throws `app` is not defined in controller and model file
Here is the controller file -

```
 'use strict';  
app.controller('SampleCtrl', function ($scope,
                                       $location,
                                       $routeParams,
                                       SampleModel) {

 console.log('this is a test controller');
});
```

All the files are included in index.html and the resources are loading correctly which I checked by chrome developer tool but I can't find the reason why it says app not defined. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As they are separate files and grunt/jshint will not know that the variable is available in other files. Instead of that it would be a best practice to use it in this way:

Instead use this:

```
angular.module('myTestApp')
 .controller('SampleCtrl', function ($scope,
                                       $location,
                                       $routeParams,
                                       SampleModel) {

 console.log('this is a test controller');
});
```

Another general pattern you might have noticed in most the other's code, wrapping the code inside an IIFE.

```
(function() {
"use strict";

 var app = angular.module('myTestApp')
     app.controller('SampleCtrl', function ($scope,
                                           $location,
                                           $routeParams,
                                           SampleModel) {

     console.log('this is a test controller');
    });

})();
```

In this app will not pollute the global namespace and it's local to that function.

Here if you've noticed, I've not used `[]` while using `angular.module()`, it means that we're just getting that module.

So in your app.'s alone, it will be with `[]` and in other files without `[]`

```
 (function() {
    "use strict";

     var app = angular.module('myTestApp', ['ngCookies',
                                       'ngResource',
                                       'ngRoute',
                                       'ngSanitize',
                                       'ngTouch']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
         .when('sample', {
            templateUrl: 'views/sample.html',
            controller: 'sampleCtrl'
          })
     });

  })();
```

Answer (score 1):

If everything else is fine, this line is causing the issue in your code -

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 routeProvider
```

you should instead use -

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
```

And yes, if `var app` is not working, try using

```
angular.module('myTestApp')
 .controller('SampleCtrl',...
```

Comment: .module without [] did not work for me as suggested above. However, the following modified code did: 

`angular.module('myTestApp', [])
 .controller('SampleCtrl',...`